# Puppeteer QuerySelector Cannot read property 'textContent' of Null

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, chromium

Trying to scrape some data about vulnerabilities using Nodejs and Puppeteer, ran into an issue where some properties are showing as null or empty, but running the SelectorQuery in the browser works ( Version 87.0.4280.88 (x86_64) ). below is a snippet that produces the issues.

The Selectors are for the date that the vulnerability is patched where the selector path is 'div.patched'. The issue seems to also happen with the software section with the following selector 'spec-title for-l' as well.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const url = 'https://www.zero-day.cz/database/';
const selector = '.issue.col-md-6';
(async function(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const version = await page.browser().version();
    console.log(version);
    await page.goto(url);
    const articles = await page.$$eval(selector, nodes => {
        return nodes.map(node => {
            let timePatched = node.querySelectorAll('div.patched').textContent;
            {};
            return {
                timePatched
            }
        })
    });
    console.log(articles);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

**Output**

```
[
  {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
  {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
  {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
  {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
  {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
  {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
  {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
  {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {},
  {}, {}, {}, {},
  ... 374 more items
]
```

- HeadlessChrome/88.0.4298.0
- Npm version 7.3
- Puppeteer version 5.5

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all you are looking for is the time the date was patched here is what I have crafted based on your code

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const url = "https://www.zero-day.cz/database/";

(async function () {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const version = await page.browser().version();
  console.log(version);
  await page.goto(url);
  const patchTimes = await page.$$eval(
    ".issue.col-md-6 div.patched",
    (patches) => patches.map((patch) => patch.textContent)
  );
  console.log(patchTimes);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Adding new snippet that grabs title/description/issue-status/patched

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://www.zero-day.cz/database/");

  const patched_texts = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".patched");
    return [...nodes].map((e) => e.textContent);
  });
  const issue_title = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".issue-title");
    return [...nodes].map((e) => e.textContent);
  });
  const desc = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".description");
    return [...nodes].map((e) => e.textContent);
  });
  const issue_status = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".issue-status");
    return [...nodes].map((e) => e.textContent);
  });
  console.log(issue_title);
  console.log(desc);
  console.log(issue_status);
  console.log(patched_texts);

  console.log(patchedTexts);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

This grabs the information you are looking for. You will now need to work with this script for whatever format you are looking to put together

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working. but how can I extend it to also add the title, description, and date discovered?

Comment: I'm waiting on a reply from Pavel because I really like the way he writes his js code and I want to learn from him as well. If there is no response in two days, I will hop on and help I promise

Comment: Hi Kyle, thank you again for your help. I am struggling to extend it to include everything and need to get the work done soon so apologies for the rush. If you have any ideas, please let me know. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi Matt, I am grinding work tomorrow, I will prioritize this script first :)

Comment: Made some additions

Answer (score 1):

Don't complicate things, keep it as simple as possible. For example, to get to the dates of patches, you can use `.patched` selector only, it gives you the same number of elements as when you use it in combination with `.issue.col-md-6`.

Another thing is you have 3 levels of indentation in `page.$$eval()`, that's not very readable. Try to simplify things as much as you can.

Here is the code that gives me an array of patch dates (450 of them):

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.zero-day.cz/database/');    
    
    const patchedTexts = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.patched');
        return [...nodes].map(e => e.textContent);
    });

    console.log(patchedTexts);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

The output is:

```
[
  '2021-01-12', '2020-12-15', '2020-12-14', '2020-12-07', '2020-11-11',
  '2020-11-11', '2020-11-06', '2020-11-06', '2020-11-06', '2020-11-03',
  '2020-11-03', '2020-11-10', '2020-10-20', '2020-10-20', '2020-09-01',
  ...
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working. but how can I extend it to also add the title, description, and date discovered?